# Running parallel Testng tests in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a BaseClass which has @BeforeSuite method that takes browser and other login parameters from xml. I want to run 2 parallel tests with different parameters. Since i am using parameters in @BeforeSuite so it takes values only once and not running any parallel execution. I cannot use parameters in @BeforeTest or @BeforeMethod or @BeforeClass as I need to use these parameters only once for each test and i have multiple test cases in each class.

My xml is as below;

```
    <listeners>
    <listener class-name="Utility.Listeners" />
    </listeners>     

 <test name="Tests1" >  

      <parameter name="Browser" value="chrome" />   
 <parameter name="username" value="d1" />   
 <parameter name="password" value="P1" />       
 <parameter name="Brand" value="TC" />


    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="NatP"  />  
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes  > 
     <class name="Maven.Dashboard"/>
     <class name="Maven.TopBottomWidget"/>
     <class name="Maven.Dashboard_BE"/>    

     </classes>
</test>
```

```
      <parameter name="Browser" value="chrome" />   
 <parameter name="username" value="d1K" />  
 <parameter name="password" value="P1K" />      
 <parameter name="Brand" value="TCK" />


    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="NatP"  />  
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes  >


     <class name="Maven.Dashboard"/>
     <class name="Maven.TopBottomWidget"/>
     <class name="Maven.Dashboard_BE"/>    

    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You could try programmatic execution of testng by using the below code. You have to pass the parameters as maven run time arguments like below,

**mvn clean install exec:java "-Dexec.mainClass=org.package.Test" "-DskipTests" "-Dexec.classpathScope=test" "-DBrowser=chrome,firefox"**

The Test class is present inside **src/test/java/**, hence the classpathScope is mentioned as **test** in the above command. Also using the above maven command we are executing the main function of the Test class. This main method will in turn trigger the testng execution. The main method parse the existing testng XML file and add the arguments as parameters to each test. Each test will be run parallel with the thread size equal to the number of arguments you pass.

```
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
    import org.testng.TestNG;
    import org.testng.xml.Parser;
    import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
    import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<String> browserList = StringUtils.isEmpty(System.
                getProperty("Browser")) ? new ArrayList<>() :
                Arrays.asList(System.getProperty("Browser").split(","));
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        File initialFile = new File("testng.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(initialFile);
        Parser p = new Parser(inputStream);
        List<XmlSuite> suites = p.parseToList();
        List<XmlSuite> modifiedSuites = new ArrayList<>();
        for (XmlSuite suite : suites) {
            XmlSuite modifiedSuite = new XmlSuite();
            modifiedSuite.setParallel(suite.getParallel());
            modifiedSuite.setThreadCount(browserList.size());
            modifiedSuite.setName(suite.getName());
            modifiedSuite.setListeners(suite.getListeners());
            List<XmlTest> tests = suite.getTests();
            for (XmlTest test : tests) {
                for (int i = 0; i < browserList.size(); i++) {
                    XmlTest modifedtest = new XmlTest(modifiedSuite);
                    HashMap<String, String> parametersMap = new HashMap<>();
                    parametersMap.put("browser", browserList.get(i));

                    modifedtest.setParameters(parametersMap);
                    modifedtest.setXmlClasses(test.getXmlClasses());
                }
            }
            modifiedSuites.add(modifiedSuite);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        tng.setXmlSuites(modifiedSuites);
        tng.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a complicated solution since i have never used run time arguments. I would appreciate if there is any other solution to this problem.

Comment: @ShaheryarKhawar you could also try using a dataprovider class with testng.